# Referer not getting sent in GET request, but sent in POST on Ionic/Capacitor app

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, networking, wkwebview

I'm in the midst of integrating an app with Ionic (v5) /Capacitor (v2.4.2). On iOS, my URL is `capacitor://localhost`. When I'm trying to load up iframes from a third-party source, I notice that the request is always failing because the `Referer` field isn't getting sent from the `WKWebView`, as compared to what I would expect when I do the same, but load up the files from my desktop browser.

Reading the link on the [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) field, I see that the browser doesn't send in the `Referer` field in the browser if the protocol is not `http` or `https`.

Looking at Google/SO answers, I can't find any previous answers that might address my use case, but I'm trying to be able to load up the iframes for my credit card form on my Ionic integration.

Are there any ways to make this work, and is my understanding of the bottleneck correct, where it's the fact that the custom URI schema present on my Ionic iOS app is causing the `Referer` from not being sent in the GET request?

<strike>I notice that it is being sent in the POST requests, so I am really curious here.</strike>. The `Origin` was being sent in the POST requests, apologies.

Would appreciate any advice on this.